# Minimum cut through vertices/nodes - not edges

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, max-flow-min-cut

we all know and love s-t minimum cut algorithms, but they all cut through the edges in the graph. Are there any variants that cuts through nodes?

Comment: This smells like homework.  (I just covered this in class last week.)

Comment: @JeffE: Sure, I'm a student and this is for a project - but there is no harm in asking, right? If one does not know what to search for, this is OK?

Comment: homework questions are *not* welcome on this site, that is the reason for Jeff's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See, for example, p. 205 and Theorem 11.7 of Bondy and Murty's *[Graph Theory with Applications](http://www.ecp6.jussieu.fr/pageperso/bondy/books/gtwa/gtwa.html)* (1976).

"[Menger's theorem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem)" is a good keyword for further googling. The usual max-flow min-cut theorem implies the edge-connectivity version of the theorem, but you are interested in the vertex-connectivity version.

(These are existential results, but a typical proof of the vertex-connectivity version reduces the problem to the edge-connectivity version, and then you can apply efficient max-flow/min-cut algorithms.)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [Minimum Vertex K-cut](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ro/online/viggo_wwwcompendium/node91.html). Also, if you search for [k-node-connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) you will get papers related to the structural properties of such cuts.

Comment: Your link to "Minimum Vertex K-cut" points to a definition of a *hard* problem (and related approximability results). Minimum vertex cut can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the algorithm? Any reference will be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It is not very difficult to transform the vertices problem to an equivalent edge version.

```
Consider a vertex v. Replace v with v1 and v2. 
Join v1 and v2 with an edge of capacity 1.
All the incoming edges into v go into v1 and all the outgoing edges from v, leave v2.
ie (u v) -> (u v1) and (v w) -> (v2 w)
This is equivalent to edge version of the s-t min cut algorithm.
```

Comment: I also felt the same. Can you think about any reference in this regard?